# How can I return a plot from for loop in R?

Tags: r, plot, return

I am trying to write a program for bisection method and try to plot the points also at each iteration.

Here is the code I have tried.

```
Bisec = function(f,a =1, b =2, max=1e10, tol = 1e-100){
  midVals = c()
  for (i in 1:max){
    c = (a+b)/2
    midVals = append(midVals,c)
    if(abs(f(c)) < tol){
      return(list(c,plot(f),points(midVals)))
    }else if(f(a)*f(c) > 0){
    a = c  
    }else{
      b =c 
    }
      }
  print("Maximum iterations reached")
}
x = var('x')
f = function(x){x*x-2}
Bisec(f,1, 3, max=1e5, tol = 1e-10)
```

But I am getting the graphs like this. [image]

### What do I need?

- the function f has to be plotted.
- the midpoints found in each iteration should be plotted in x axis.

How to achieve this?

Any hint may be helpful.  I dont know where am I goint wrong.

Comment: Try `return(list(c,plot(f),midVals))` and `x <- Bisec(f,1, 3, max=1e5, tol = 1)` and `plot(x[[2]]$x, x[[2]]$y, type="l", xlim=c(0,3))
points(x[[3]])`. But I don't know what you expect with your points.
`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I get this error with this `Error: unexpected symbol in "plot(x[[2]]$x, x[[2]]$y, type="l", xlim=c(0,3)) points"`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Regarding the `points(midVals)`: I am trying to show the midpoints calculated in the iteration on the xaxis.

Comment: Is the question off-topic here?? Should be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: No, codereview is for working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R notation can be a little different if you learned to program in a different language.  Part of R's power is it's integration between an interpreted interface and (fast) compiled functions.  Generally (although this may be an exception, I'm not focusing on that), `for` loops are avoided (many functions are vectorized, which means they do the looping within the compiled portion of the code).  We also avoid defining empty variables, because they have to be copied and pasted EVERY time you want to add something to them.

For your specific problem, `plot` *is* plotting `f` - it just doesn't know anything about the `points` command because it evaluates `plot` before it ever sees `points`.   You might find `ggplot2` gives a more dynamic solution, but I'll start with a base R approach to your function:

```
Bisec = function(f,a =1, b =2, max_iter=1e10, tol = 1e-100){
  midVals = rep(NA, max_iter) # I avoid using `max` since that's a function to find the maximum

  for (i in 1:max_iter){
    x <- mean(c(a,b)) # I also avoid using `c` since that's a function to concatenate stuff
    midVals[i] <- x

    if(abs(f(x)) < tol){
      plot(f, xlim = range(midVals, na.rm = TRUE))
      points(midVals, rep(0,length(midVals))
      return(x)
    } else if(f(a)*f(x) > 0){
    a = x  
    }
    else{
      b = x 
    }
  }
  print("Maximum iterations reached")
}
```

Comment: Just for curiocity...` na.rm = TRUE` removes the values `NA while ploting right??

Comment: May be a printing mistake in the for loop? ..`max = max_iter`

Comment: I get this error `Error in x * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: I fixed a few issues where I didn't replace `c` and `max` with `x` and `max_iter`.  `na.rm` removes the NAs when calculating the range.  Otherwise, you're range will be `(NA, NA)` and it will throw an error.

Comment: This plots the mid points on the graph of `f`. I want them to be plotted on the `xaxis`.

Comment: updated accordingly. By default, the first argument of `points` is the location on the x-axis and he 2nd argument is the location on the y-axis.   So I simply changed the vector of points for the y-axis.  If you want to change other features, try `?points`, which will bring up the help file with some examples.  For example, the `pch` argument will let you change the symbol.

Comment: Thats bravo.. Thank you